# Trouble handling input in Java

Tags: java, string, input

I'm trying to read input from the terminal. For this, I'm using a BufferedReader. Here's my code.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] args;
do {
    System.out.println(stateManager.currentState().toString());
    System.out.print("> ");
    args = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    // user inputs "Hello World"
} while (args[0].equals(""));
```

Somewhere else in my code I have a `HashTable` where the Key and Values are both Strings. Here's the problem:

If I want to get a value from the `HashTable` where the key I'm using to look up in the `HashTable` is one of the args elements. These args are weird. If the user enters two arguments (the first one is a command, the second is what the user wants to look up) I can't find a match.

For example, if the HashTable contains the following values:

```
[ {"Hello":"World"}, {"One":"1"}, {"Two":"2"} ]
```

and the user enters:

```
get Hello
```

My code doesn't return `"World"`.

So I used the debugger (using Eclipse) to see what's inside of `args`. I found that `args[1]` contains `"Hello"` but inside `args[1]` there is a field named `value` which  has the value `['g','e','t',' ','H','e','l','l','o']`.

The same goes for `args[0]`. It contains `"get"` but the field `value` contains `['g','e','t',' ','H','e','l','l','o']`!

What the hell!!!

However, if I check my `HashTable`, wherever the key is `"Hello"`, the value=`['H','e','l','l','o']`.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

---

EDIT:

Here's come code sample. The same is still happening.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class InputTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(        System.in));
        Hashtable<String, String> EngToSpa = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    // Adding some elements to the Eng-Spa dictionary
    EngToSpa.put("Hello", "Hola");
    EngToSpa.put("Science", "Ciencia");
    EngToSpa.put("Red", "Rojo");

    // Reads input. We are interested in everything after the first argument
    do
    {
        System.out.print("> ");
        try
        {
            args = reader.readLine().trim().split("\\s");
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (args[0].equals("") || args.length < 2); 
    // ^ We don't want empty input or less than 2 args.

    // Lets go get something in the dictionary

    System.out.println("Testing arguments");

    if (!EngToSpa.contains(args[1]))
        System.out.println("Word not found!");
    else
        System.out.println(EngToSpa.get(args[1]));

    // Now we are testing the word "Hello" directly
    System.out.println("Testing 'Hello'");

    if (!EngToSpa.contains("Hello"))
        System.out.println("Word not found!");
    else
        System.out.println(EngToSpa.get("Hello"));

}
}
```

The same is still happening. I must be misunderstanding Hash Tables. Ideas where things are going wrong?

Comment: Since your problem is putting and getting entries in a hash table, post that code. The relevance of the code provide is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed my mistake. I have to use *containsKey()*  instead of *contains()*.

I'd like to thank everyone for helping.

As a bonus, I also learned about what the 'value' field is. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the value field - that's just saying that there's a single char array containing the text of "get Hello", and both args[0] and args[1] *refer* to that char array, but they'll have different offsets and counts. args[0] will have an offset of 0 and a count of 3; args[1] will have an offset of 4 and a count of 5.

I've no idea why your hash map wouldn't be working though... can you provide a short but complete example program?

Answer (score 0):

As Jon said, you're just seeing an artifact of the internal implementation of `String`s in Java.  You can ignore the `value` field for your purposes.  That has nothing to do with why things aren't working for you.  You need to show us the part of the code that's not working.